# How can i know which link I clicked?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, bootstrap-modal

I'm deploying a table where you can edit the columns. For that, in each cell there's an `<a>` to show a modal to change que value in the database and refresh the page. For now it does well the modal appearing but for the moment the modal appears, the code doesn't know which link was clicked. I need to know it to get the `id` of the row. The JQuery method that calls the last button of the modal ('Guardar') needs to call a php script by AJAX and send the id of the row (to make the UPDATE statement) and the new value of the column.

I tried to use the methods `closest()` and `find()` from JQuery and to set a the id of the row in a data-id attribute.

This is where I deploy the table vía PHP(code is simplified to one column to read and understand it better)

```
if($resHitos->num_rows>0){
    while ($columna = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resHitos)) {
        $id=$columna['id'];
        echo "<tr data-id='$id'>";
        echo "<td style='text-align:center'><p><a data-toggle='modal' data-target='#modalEditHito'>".$columna['descripcion']."</a></p></td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
}
```

**This is the modal**

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modalEditarHito" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title">Editar objetivo</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="newObjetivo">Objetivo</label>
                        <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="editObjetivo"></textarea><br>
                 </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" onclick="editDescripcionHito()">Guardar</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The expected result is to see the new value inputed in the exact row that was clicked.

Comment: [This example from the docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/#varying-modal-content) shows how to add a jQuery event listener that can be used to read the data from the row.

Comment: in your javascript function can you not simply use `event.target`

Comment: @RamRaider no because that function wasn't executed by an event

Comment: @ChrisG This is some good help! Thanks!

Comment: you can still register an event listener on the document to listen and respond...

Comment: @RamRaider ```$('#modalEditHito').on('show.bs.modal', function(event))``` there? Im trying like that but the function is not executed.

Comment: within `function(event){....` I'd say

Comment: @RamRaider i have an ```alert()``` on the beginning of the method but it's not executed when the modal appears.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193981/discussion-between-ramraider-and-wasanga7).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add listener event on your modal when it is displayed.

```
$(document).on('show.bs.modal','#modalEditHito', function (e) {
  var $invoker = $(e.relatedTarget);
  //this may help
  //var tr = $invoker.closest('tr');
  //var tr_id = tr.attr("data-id");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a data attribute to uniquely identify rows. or you can simply add id attribute like this

```
 echo '<tr data-id=".$columnna['id'].">';
```

You should change this line
`echo "<td style='text-align:center'><p><a data-toggle='modal' data-target='#modalEditHito'>".$columna['descripcion']."</a></p></td>";`

to

`echo "<td style='text-align:center'><p><a data-toggle='modal' data-target='#modalEditHito".$columnna['id']."'>".$columna['descripcion']."</a></p></td>";`

Comment: Why adding the ```id``` to the modal-target?

Comment: @wasanga7 you'll always have a single modal?? and it will show content on the basis of row click?? Is this what you want?? 
I added to ```modal-target``` because i thought each row have a separate modal

Comment: Each row display the same modal, but the modal has to managed the information of the row (id).